# Can't install My Batis generator to Eclipse Mars

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, mybatis, mybatis-generator

I'm trying to install My Batis generator to Eclipse Mars. Now, I've installed it to other computer without problems (it was 32 bit computer, and win 7) from this source:

http://mybatis.googlecode.com/svn/sub-projects/generator/trunk/eclipse/UpdateSite/

For some reason, I can't install it now on my other machine, 64 bit windows. Eclipse just won't find that path (I think it has to do with the proxies my company relies on, but I don't understant why it is passing then on 32 bit computers and here, only in my example it won't on 64 bit computers).

What to do. Can I just grab pom.xml from here and install it manually?

http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.mybatis.generator%7Cmybatis-generator%7C1.3.2%7C

But, there it seems there are other related artifacts in that pom which i don't want to install and use (I'm not sure how to precisely configure Maven at this point). What to do then? 
Can't I create emtpy pom.xml file and write it like this (I've not included maven headers here):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mybatis.generator</groupId>
    <artifactId>mybatis-generator</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I need to install My Batis generator and Eclipse won't do me, so I am trying to find quickest solution.. what to do?

Comment: You can use 'wget -mkEpnp http://mybatis.googlecode.com/svn/sub-projects/generator/trunk/eclipse/UpdateSite/' to mirror it to local folder and then try to install from it.